# Регулярное выражение

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать регулярное выражение, которое могло бы достать любую ссылку из данного тэга:

> meta property="og:image" content="https://scontent-fra3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/14276400_1742191619336501_90536135_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMzMjc1MzEzNjkzMDQzMTEyNQ%3D%3D.2" / >

Answer (score 3):

Для получения ссылок **HTTP** и **HTTPS**

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

Дополнительно можно почитать [оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/3926506)

Comment: Не подходит, java ругается на знаки _ и \/\/(www\.)

Comment: Добавил экранирование, попробуй так

Comment: Не, всё равно что-то не нравится. Но я вроде нашёл другой способ. Попробую через jsoup сделать.Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Хорошо, обязательно опубликуй правильный ответ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Сделал при помощи *Jsoup*:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(metaTag);
Element element = doc.select("meta").first();
String link = element.attr("content");
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, но вопрос был именно в том, как сделать это регулярным выражением

Comment: Регулярное выражение я так и не нашел)